# Turn a string that is a formatted list into a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string

```
'[comedy, drama]'
```

that is a type str but appears to look like a list.  Is there a quick change I can apply to turn it into a list with the two entries being both type str?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> '[comedy, drama]'[1:-1].split(', ')
['comedy', 'drama']
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickest is

```
>>> s = '[comedy, drama]'
>>> s[1:-1].split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the brackets and `,` part of the string?  If so, you can just use `str.split` and `str.strip`.

```
s = '[comedy, drama, tragedy]'
wordList = s.replace(" ", "").strip("[]").split(",")
```

I have included `s.replace(" ", "")` so that it is agnostic as to whether they are split by ", " or by just ",", even mixed is fine.